# python qt5 thread don't refresh controls in real time

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread

I'm writing an UI using QT5 and python, I added a thread to handle the UI, thread works "*fine*", a function inside the thread receive 2 strings and return 2 strings (I'm making experiments before develop the real project just to see how it works), as you can see in the code after call the thread function with:

```
self.requestConexion.emit('lblText1','dddddd')
```

I call another function that is just a simple counter

```
self.contador()
```

so I expect that before the counter finish the value of the control self.lblText1 change, but this is not happen... here is the main code:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import UI_test
import time
import sys

class Threaded(QObject):
    result=pyqtSignal(str,str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, **kwargs)

    @pyqtSlot(str,str)
    def etiquetas(self,lbl,texto):
        print(texto)
        self.result.emit(lbl,texto)


class MainApp(QMainWindow, UI_test.Ui_MainWindow):
    requestConexion=pyqtSignal(str,str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self._thread=QThread()
        self._threaded=Threaded(result=self.displayLabel)
        self.requestConexion.connect(self._threaded.etiquetas)
        self._threaded.moveToThread(self._thread)
        qApp.aboutToQuit.connect(self._thread.quit)
        self._thread.start()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnStart.clicked.connect(self.conexion)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def conexion(self):
        #self._thread.start()
        print(1)
        self.requestConexion.emit('lblText1','dddddd')
        self.contador()
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Text Input Dialog', 'Enter your name:')
        if ok:
             print(str(text))

    @pyqtSlot()
    def contador(self):
        i=0
        while i<50:
            print(i)
            time.sleep(0.1)
            i+=1

    @pyqtSlot(str,str)
    def displayLabel(self, etiqueta, texto):
        self.lblText1.setText(etiqueta)
        print(texto)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    form = MainApp()                 
    form.show()                         
    app.exec_()                         
    exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':              
    main()
```

any idea whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer to my question in the next blog:

https://martinfitzpatrick.name/article/multithreading-pyqt-applications-with-qthreadpool/

this is a really great tutorial, after read the documentation in the blog I was able to modify one of the examples to modify the text of a label control in real time;  here is the final code:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import time

class Worker(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()        
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.fn = fn

    @pyqtSlot()
    def run(self):
        #print(self.args, self.kwargs)
        print("Thread start") 
        time.sleep(0.2)
        self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)  #ejecuta la funcion recibida


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        print("Multithreading with maximum %d threads" % self.threadpool.maxThreadCount())

        self.counter = 0

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.l = QLabel("Start")
        self.l2 = QLabel("xxxxx")
        b = QPushButton("DANGER!")
        b.pressed.connect(self.oh_no)

        layout.addWidget(self.l)
        layout.addWidget(self.l2)
        layout.addWidget(b)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)

        self.show()

        self.etiqueta="rrrrrrrrrr"

        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(500)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.recurring_timer)
        self.timer.start()

    def oh_no(self):
        self.etiqueta="hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh"
        worker = Worker(self.execute_this_fn,'4444')
        self.threadpool.start(worker)

    def recurring_timer(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.l.setText("Counter: %d" % self.counter)


    def execute_this_fn(self,x):
        print("Hello!")
        self.l2.setText(x)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: The GUI should not be updated from another thread, in your case you are updating it using `self.l2.setText(x)`, that's what the signals are for, so you understand better read the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread